# Convert HTML table to dropdown (or otherwise getting a select tag with columns)

Tags: html, html-select, javascript

What I have in my code right now:

```
<select>
   <option value="...">Dr. Steve 555-222-9393</option>
   <option value="...">Jim 333-999-1111</option>
   <option value="...">New Emergency Services 0118-999-881-99-9119-7253</option>
</select>
```

It looks bad, and after a few dozen entries it's very, *very* hard to read.

What I'd like is to emulate a dropdown by using a table and then displaying just one row of the table at a time (with the currently selected row's value stored in a hidden input).

The question: before I start writing it myself, has someone already done this (in any library)?  I've been going through the jquery plugin registry and there are plenty of plugins for converting `<ul>` to behave like `<select>` and tons to create fancy multi-selects. (Some of these might even work, if you could disable the multi- part.  SE's own Tags input has pretty fancy formatting in its "dropdown".) But if there's one that can turn a `<table>` (or anything else) into a select-with-columns, it's lost in the noise.

Note: I've found a number of [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853794/how-to-convert-html-table-into-a-dropdown-list-while-keeping-alignment-of-text) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790915/html-dropdown-multi-columns)  that suggest using monospace fonts and padding to line data up in a plain select tag, but I'd like to think it can be done better, especially after seeing jquery plugins like Chosen.

Comment: Why do you have to display that information as a select list?
_Sometimes the solution is right outside the box_

Comment: if you've already got the table created (I don't think you do), why don't you just obtain all the values in Column 1 and store them into an array. Then, in your select element, loop through your array and populate the options

Comment: Maybe a select with a `size` attribute helps. In Firefox that converts the dropdown into a selection list, not sure what it will do in other browsers.

Comment: @Eyal I am aiming for the data to be displayed as (part of) a table, but have the *behavior* of a select list.  This fits into a form with other information to fill out about this contact, having a table of radio buttons with dozens to hundreds of rows (choose one) that someone will have to scroll through to continue the form is not as usable as a widget that works the way users expect it to work, but presents the data in a readable format.

Comment: The element would have poor usability anyway, due to the size of the options. Use a set of radio buttons instead. Then you can put things into a table, with the buttons in one column, the other data in other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find anything that could convert a table to a dropdown with columns but I was able to use [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/)'s `data-text` attribute to fake it with `inline-block`:

```
<select>
<option value="1" data-search="555-555-5555 Bob" data-text="<span style=&quot;display:inline-block; min-width:10em; margin-right:1em;&quot;>555-555-5555</span><span style=&quot;display:inline-block;&quot;>Bob</span>"></option>
<option value="2" data-search="444-444-4444 Steve" data-text="<span style=&quot;display:inline-block; min-width:10em; margin-right:1em;&quot;>444-444-4444</span><span style=&quot;display:inline-block;&quot;>Steve</span>"></option>
</select>
```

`data-search` is required in order for type-to-search to work (otherwise, it appears to expect the user to type the HTML as it appears in `data-text`). More work would be needed to make the columns line up if someone really entered a phone number like 0118-999-881-99-9119-7253.